# Using two SQL tables to fetch JSON data for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm using an SQL query to fetch data from a database and return it as JSON data to send to a Javascript file. I'm using two different tables from the database for the SQL query. How do I join the two tables or what code do I need to use to store the data from the two tables as one JSON data to be sent to the Javascript file?

I want to return the team names and the province names to be displayed in a table in the Javascript file. The SQL query I'm using gets the correct data when I use it in MySQL Workbench but doesn't work for Teams.php. I want to display the team names in the Teams column and the province names in the Provinces column in the Javascript file.

The JSON data currently displays the data in Teams.php as { "teams":[{"name":"Ulster"},{"name":"Ulster"},{"name":"Ulster"},{"name":"Leinster"}]} which is wrong as it only displays one name and it's fetching the wrong data too because they are the province names.

I want it to be displayed as { "teams":[{"name":"Donegal","province":"Ulster"},{"name":"Derry","province":"Ulster"},{"name":"Down","province":"Ulster"},{"name":"Dublin","province":"Leinster"}]} as it shows the team name and the province name.

Teams.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Teams.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Teams</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter team name: <input id="team" type="text" /></td>               
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Teams.js

```
var xmlhttp;

window.onload=function(){
    init();
}

function init()
{
    // call getAjaxData() as the user types text 
    document.getElementById("team").onkeyup=function(){
        getAjaxData();
    }
}

function getAjaxData()
{   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   

    // put the text typed into a JavaScript variable 'teamname'
    var teamname=document.getElementById("team").value;
    console.log(teamname);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showData;
    // make Ajax request using the text typed OR you could first request "Teams.json"
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Teams.php?name="+teamname, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}

function showData()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {           
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);        

        // build a html table with the data returned
        var output = '<table border=1>';
        output += '<th>Team</th><th>Province</th>';

        for (var i=0;i<data.teams.length;i++) {         
            output += '<tr><td>'+ data.teams[i].name +'</td><td>' + data.teams[i].province +'</td></tr>';
        }
        output += '</table>';

        // add output to div
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=output;
    }
}
```

Teams.php

```
<?php
$team=$_GET['name'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connection,"gaadb");

// I'd recommend finding just the team names first.
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT t.name, p.name FROM teams AS t, provinces AS p WHERE p.id = t.province AND t.name like '$team%'");

$rs = array();
$i=0;
while($rs[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
}
mysqli_close($connection);
unset($rs[count($rs)-1]);  //removes a null value
print("{ \"teams\":" . json_encode($rs) . "} ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@GleneaMan First of all focus on your **SQL query**. your team table must have province id so that on behalf of `province_id` you can use the **join** of two tables correctly.

Secondly you have to manipulate the json data accordingly.

In your current query data provinces names repeated with number of teams.